# Invalid EmbeddedDocumentField item while saving instance of django mongoengine model (fails on save())

Tags: python, django, mongodb, model, mongoengine

I am trying to save an instance of a model but I get

```
Invalid EmbeddedDocumentField item (1)
```

where `1` is item's id (I think).

Model is defined as

```
class Graph(Document):
    user = StringField(max_length=50, required=True)
    title = StringField(max_length=500)
    description = StringField(max_length=1000)
    # field in error
    graph_nodes = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Graph_Node))
    procedure = ListField(DictField())
    created_on = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    meta = {
        'ordering': ['-created_on'],
        'allow_inheritance': False,
    }


class Graph_Node(EmbeddedDocument):
    id = StringField(required=True, max_length=30)
    button = StringField(max_length=40, required=True)
    parameter = StringField(max_length=50, required=False)
    values = ListField(StringField(max_length=30, required=False))
    wires_out = ListField(StringField(max_length=30, required=False))
    wires_in = ListField(StringField(max_length=30, required=False))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id

    meta = {
        'allow_inheritance': False
    }

    def fill(self, args):
        for k in args.keys():
            if k in self.__dict__['_data'].keys():
                self.__dict__['_data'][k] = args[k]
```

Call for `save()` method is the following:

```
Graph(user=request.user.username, title=title, 
      description=description, procedure=procedura, 
      graph_nodes=gnlist).save()
```

And exception is thrown on `save`, not on Graph creation.

`gnlist` is (from `pydev debugger`)

```
list: [<Graph_Node: start>, <Graph_Node: 1>, <Graph_Node: end>]
```

and `gnlist[1]` seems to be well formed (I'll post more details if needed)

I've tried to trace the query on `mongodb` but it doesn't seem to be profiled, however output follows (in case help me to purge it from irrelevant logs):

```
{ "ts" : ISODate("2012-10-26T18:25:07.492Z"), "op" : "query", "ns" : "analysis.system.indexes", "query" : { "expireAfterSeconds" : { "$exists" : true } }, "ntoreturn" : 0, "ntoskip" : 0, "nscanned" : 0, "keyUpdates" : 0, "numYield" : 0, "lockStats" : { "timeLockedMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(248), "w" : NumberLong(0) }, "timeAcquiringMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(2), "w" : NumberLong(4) } }, "nreturned" : 0, "responseLength" : 20, "millis" : 0, "client" : "0.0.0.0", "user" : "" }
{ "ts" : ISODate("2012-10-26T18:26:07.505Z"), "op" : "query", "ns" : "analysis.system.indexes", "query" : { "expireAfterSeconds" : { "$exists" : true } }, "ntoreturn" : 0, "ntoskip" : 0, "nscanned" : 0, "keyUpdates" : 0, "numYield" : 0, "lockStats" : { "timeLockedMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(680), "w" : NumberLong(0) }, "timeAcquiringMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(4), "w" : NumberLong(7) } }, "nreturned" : 0, "responseLength" : 20, "millis" : 0, "client" : "0.0.0.0", "user" : "" }
{ "ts" : ISODate("2012-10-26T18:26:25.803Z"), "op" : "query", "ns" : "analysis.system.profile", "query" : { }, "ntoreturn" : 0, "ntoskip" : 0, "nscanned" : 2, "keyUpdates" : 0, "numYield" : 0, "lockStats" : { "timeLockedMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(62), "w" : NumberLong(0) }, "timeAcquiringMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(7), "w" : NumberLong(3) } }, "nreturned" : 2, "responseLength" : 758, "millis" : 0, "client" : "127.0.0.1", "user" : "" }
{ "ts" : ISODate("2012-10-26T18:27:07.506Z"), "op" : "query", "ns" : "analysis.system.indexes", "query" : { "expireAfterSeconds" : { "$exists" : true } }, "ntoreturn" : 0, "ntoskip" : 0, "nscanned" : 0, "keyUpdates" : 0, "numYield" : 0, "lockStats" : { "timeLockedMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(698), "w" : NumberLong(0) }, "timeAcquiringMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(6), "w" : NumberLong(7) } }, "nreturned" : 0, "responseLength" : 20, "millis" : 0, "client" : "0.0.0.0", "user" : "" }
{ "ts" : ISODate("2012-10-26T18:27:18.817Z"), "op" : "query", "ns" : "analysis.system.profile", "query" : { }, "ntoreturn" : 0, "ntoskip" : 0, "nscanned" : 4, "keyUpdates" : 0, "numYield" : 0, "lockStats" : { "timeLockedMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(121), "w" : NumberLong(0) }, "timeAcquiringMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(11), "w" : NumberLong(8) } }, "nreturned" : 4, "responseLength" : 1463, "millis" : 0, "client" : "127.0.0.1", "user" : "" }
{ "ts" : ISODate("2012-10-26T18:28:02.570Z"), "op" : "query", "ns" : "analysis.system.profile", "query" : { }, "ntoreturn" : 0, "ntoskip" : 0, "nscanned" : 5, "keyUpdates" : 0, "numYield" : 0, "lockStats" : { "timeLockedMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(112), "w" : NumberLong(0) }, "timeAcquiringMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(13), "w" : NumberLong(7) } }, "nreturned" : 5, "responseLength" : 1799, "millis" : 0, "client" : "127.0.0.1", "user" : "" }
{ "ts" : ISODate("2012-10-26T18:28:07.507Z"), "op" : "query", "ns" : "analysis.system.indexes", "query" : { "expireAfterSeconds" : { "$exists" : true } }, "ntoreturn" : 0, "ntoskip" : 0, "nscanned" : 0, "keyUpdates" : 0, "numYield" : 0, "lockStats" : { "timeLockedMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(680), "w" : NumberLong(0) }, "timeAcquiringMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(5), "w" : NumberLong(7) } }, "nreturned" : 0, "responseLength" : 20, "millis" : 0, "client" : "0.0.0.0", "user" : "" }
{ "ts" : ISODate("2012-10-26T18:28:11.608Z"), "op" : "query", "ns" : "analysis.system.profile", "query" : { }, "ntoreturn" : 0, "ntoskip" : 0, "nscanned" : 7, "keyUpdates" : 0, "numYield" : 0, "lockStats" : { "timeLockedMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(117), "w" : NumberLong(0) }, "timeAcquiringMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(10), "w" : NumberLong(7) } }, "nreturned" : 7, "responseLength" : 2504, "millis" : 0, "client" : "127.0.0.1", "user" : "" }
{ "ts" : ISODate("2012-10-26T18:28:51.589Z"), "op" : "command", "ns" : "analysis.$cmd", "command" : { "profile" : 0 }, "ntoreturn" : 1, "keyUpdates" : 0, "numYield" : 0, "lockStats" : { "timeLockedMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(0), "w" : NumberLong(24) }, "timeAcquiringMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(0), "w" : NumberLong(11) } }, "responseLength" : 58, "millis" : 0, "client" : "127.0.0.1", "user" : "" }
```

Thanks

Comment: This looks like mongoengine. Is it? Also, could you add the full trace?

Comment: yes it is.. ok, I'll try to provide it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it is resolved:

I found [this issue](https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/issues/328).

I installed the new stable version of `mongoengine` : 0.6.2

After a restart `mongoengine` told me where was the problem:

`values` attribute was too short to hold a file path, so I changed

```
values = ListField(StringField(max_length=30, required=False))
```

to

```
values = ListField(StringField(max_length=100, required=False))
```

Thanks to all